# How to send a reset password email in Django on User creation?

Tags: python, django

I want to be able to let an admin create user accounts and then, instead of setting up a password for the user, the user would automatically receive a reset password email.

The view for the user creation, which also includes a `Member` model, is the following:

```
def newmember(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        nu_form = NewUser(request.POST)
        nm_form = NewMember(request.POST)
    
        if nu_form.is_valid() and nm_form.is_valid():
            nusave = nu_form.save()
            nmsave = nm_form.save(commit = False)
            nmsave.user = nusave
            nmsave.save()
            return redirect(members)
        else:
            print(nu_form.errors)
            print(nm_form.errors)
    
    else:

        nu_form = NewUser()
        nm_form = NewMember()

    context = {
        'nu_form': nu_form, 
        'nm_form': nm_form}
    
    return render(request, 'web/newmember.html', context)
```

How can I make so that upon creation of a new user, Django automatically sends an email to that new user requestion a password reset?

Comment: Do you have an E-Mail Server or use an E-Mail Service (e.g. sendgrid, mailgun) that can send E-Mails?

Comment: @DominikViererbe I will be using Google Workspace, given that the number of emails sent per month won't surpass 50 emails.

Comment: I found a tutorial that adresses you problem: https://muhfathurh.medium.com/send-email-with-django-using-gmail-smtp-b7461c4dfd83

I hope it helps :)

Comment: This is a tutorial on how to setup Gmail as an email service within Django, which I have already done. What I need to know if it is possible to trigger a reset password email on user creation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to send an email on user creation you need to define a method which shoot an email like below :-

1. Create a text file name such as 'email_content.txt'

   Please reset password for your profile {{username}}

   Click Here
2. Update the `newmember`  method and add below code into it :-

   ```
            template = get_template('email_content.txt')
            context = {"usename": nmsave.user.username}
            content = template.render(context)

            email = EmailMessage(
                "Congratulation, please reset your account password", content, 'App Name' <sender_email>
            )
            email.content_subtype = "html"
            email.send()
   ```

add above code in `try catch` block

Answer (score 0):

In your models.py:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    send_mail('subject', 'message', 'your email', 'user email')
    return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```